# C#: Use negative char numbers in C imported dll

Tags: c#, c++, char, negative-number

I imported a DLL that I compiled with rato.hpp:

```
#ifndef RATO_H
#define RATO_H

extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) void mouse_move(char button, char x, char y, char wheel);
}
#endif
```

and rato.cpp:

```
typedef struct {
        char button;
        char x;
        char y;
        char wheel;
        char unk1;
    } MOUSE_IO;

void mouse_move(char button, char x, char y, char wheel)
    {
        MOUSE_IO io;
        io.unk1 = 0;
        io.button = button;
        io.x = x;
        io.y = y;
        io.wheel = wheel;

        if (!callmouse(&io)) {
            mouse_close();
            mouse_open();
        }
    }
```

When importing it in my CSharp code, I can't cast negative values:

```
[DllImport("Rato.dll")]
public static extern void mouse_move(char button, char x, char y, char wheel);

mouse_move((char)0,(char)0,(char)-150,0);
```

I tried to convert, but it doesn't work, it keeps sending positive values instead of negative.

EDIT: Tried to convert to `sbyte` but get error

> System.OverflowException: 'Value was either too large or too small for a signed byte.'

```
[DllImport("Rato.dll")]
public static extern void mouse_move(sbyte button, sbyte x, sbyte y, sbyte wheel);

mouse_move(0,0,Convert.ToSByte(-150),0);
```

How can I sucessfully pass negative char value to C imported DLL?

Comment: Did you try to use `signed char` explicitly? A `char` has no default signedness.

Comment: `char` in C# isn't a numeric type, it represents a character encoded in Unicode UTF-16. C's char is equivalent to C#'s [`byte`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.byte?view=net-6.0) or [`sbyte`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.sbyte?view=net-6.0) depending on whether or not your C `char` contains negative numbers or not. In your case, you should use `sbyte`

Comment: I tryied "[DllImport("Rato.dll")] public static extern void mouse_move(sbyte button, sbyte x, sbyte y, sbyte wheel);" but it keeps casting positive (moving mouse to right, not left)

Comment: The smallest possible value of an `sbyte` (and also a `signed char` in C on most platforms) is -128. So what are you trying to achieve by sending `-150`?

Comment: Also you need `CallingConvention = CallingConvention.CDecl` in your `DllImport` attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char` in C# is a 16-bit unsigned type so obviously you can't use it to interop with `char` in C++. `sbyte` is the way to go. However the [range of `sbyte`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types) is -128 to 127, similar to `unsigned char` in C when `CHAR_BIT == 8`, so obviously -150 can't fit in C# `sbyte`/C `char`

Note: [`char` in C can be signed or unsigned](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2054939/995714), so if for example you use the [`/J` option in MSVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/j-default-char-type-is-unsigned?view=msvc-170) or the [`-funsigned-char` option in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Characters-implementation.html) in your project then you can't pass a negative value to the C function

Comment: What I need to use to achieve higher ranges?

Comment: obviously by changing your C++ code (not C, the extension is cpp) to use a wider type like `short` or `int`. Most of the time `int` would be recommended. Why don't just check your C++ book?